# Is there any Systems Dynamics software packaged for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm looking for [Systems Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_dynamics) software (e.g. [Stella](http://www.iseesystems.com/softwares/Education/StellaSoftware.aspx)) for Ubuntu, preferably open source. Recommendations for non packaged software that runs on Linux are also welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question appear to be no. These past few days I found several free or open System Dynamics programmes that should run on Ubuntu, but none is packaged at this time; some of them are just code libraries. Here's the list:

- [DynSim](http://code.google.com/p/dynsim/wiki/Intro) - a Java package, apparently undocumented.
- [MapSim](http://mapsim.sourceforge.net/) - a simulation engine for System Dynamics. Provides a .NET library that works on Windows and under Mono on Linux plus a simple GUI tool. MapSim uses its own modelling language described in a reference manual.
- [NetLogo](http://modelingcommons.org/tags/one_tag/266) - the famous agent based modelling framework; supports system dynamics models as a secondary feature.
- [Sphinx SD Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sphinxes/) - a project dedicated to create a common accessible environment for System Dynamics simulation. It is developed on the Java 6 platform and uses the Java Swing GUI.
- [SystemDynamics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/system-dynamics/) - a graphical Java application for modelling, visualisation and execution of System Dynamics models.
- [Simile](http://www.simulistics.com/) - A proprietary System Dynamics and object-based modelling and simulation software package similar to Stella, Model Maker, Vensim, etc. A free evaluation version, which limits the size of saved models, is available.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Python script library that may be of interest for Linux/Ubuntu users. Popular ones seem to be Pyndamics (http://github.com/bblais/pyndamics) and PySD (http://github.com/JamesPHoughton/pysd)